# Extending TFS to include custom fields in work items

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tfs

We have a need within our organization to add a field to Work Items that has traceability throughout TFS 2010 source control. We use ticket numbers to identify work items internally and would like to associate a TFS work item with our internal ticket numbers and then be able to run reports to gather information such as:

Which work item was associated with ticket #12345

What ticket numbers were included in a particular release branch?

Etc...

All of this starts with extending the TFS work item UI to include our custom field. Not having done any extending of TFS before, can anyone point me in the right direction with advice, URLs, tutorials, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not tried this myself, but this post may get you started:
[How to add a Custom Field to an existing Work Item Type in TFS 2010 Process Template (MSF for Agile 5.0)](http://amosdk.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-add-custom-field-to-existing.html)